# Como sumar horas y minutos en php

Tags: php, php7, php5

Estoy tratando de sumar las horas y minutos en php, lo primero es que hallo la diferencia de dos horas y lo formateo en horas y minutos y después tengo que sumar dos variables con esas horas y minutos esto es lo que tengo.

```
  $extradiurnaEntrada =  $Date_FinNocheLaboral->diff($Date_InicioJornadaLaboral);
  $extradiurnaEntrada =  $extradiurnaEntrada->format('%H:%I');

$extraDiurnaEntradaSinNoche = $Date_MovimientoEntrada->diff($Date_InicioJornadaLaboral);
$extraDiurnaEntradaSinNoche = $extraDiurnaEntradaSinNoche->format('%H:%I');
```

estas dos variables tienen por ejemplo estos datos

```
$extradiurnaEntrada  = 02:30;
 $extraDiurnaEntradaSinNoche = 02:00;
```

y el resultado que espero es 04:30;

lo he intentado con strtotime pero no me funciona

```
$DiurnasTotal = strtotime($extradiurnaEntrada) + strtotime( $extraDiurnaEntradaSinNoche);
```

de pronto alguien me puede ayudar de como hacerlo?

Answer (score 1):

Resta la marca de tiempo **del día** (en su hora cero) al segundo operando:

```
$hi = strtotime('02:30');
$hf = strtotime('02:00')-strtotime('midnight');

echo date('H:i',$hi+$hf);
```

Resultado:

```
04:30
```

Answer (score 0):

Buen día, aqui te dejo dos funcion que utilizo en varios de mis proyectos de **php** para sumar y restar horas, le coloque tus horas de ejemplo:

```
function sumar($hora1, $hora2)
{
    list($h, $m, $s) = explode(':', $hora2); //Separo los elementos de la segunda hora
    $a = new DateTime($hora1); //Creo un DateTime
    $b = new DateInterval(sprintf('PT%sH%sM%sS', $h, $m, $s)); //Creo un DateInterval
    $a->add($b); //SUMO las horas
    return $a->format('H:i:s'); //Retorno la Suma
}

function restar($hora1, $hora2)
{
    list($h, $m, $s) = explode(':', $hora2); //Separo los elementos de la segunda hora
    $a = new DateTime($hora1); //Creo un DateTime
    $b = new DateInterval(sprintf('PT%sH%sM%sS', $h, $m, $s)); //Creo un DateInterval
    $a->sub($b); //RESTO las horas
    return $a->format('H:i:s'); //Retorno la Resta
}

echo sumar('02:30:00', '02:00:00');
echo "<br>";
echo restar('02:30:00', '02:00:00');
```

Comment: me sale este error cuando utilizo la funcion  es como si no reconociera el DateInterval<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Exception: DateInterval::__construct(): Unknown or bad format (PT01H00MS) in /home/http/miclubappdev/httpdocs/admin/lib/SIMUtil.inc.php:8909

Comment: No me ha dado error, de echo mi resultado es 04:30:00 con tus datos, dejame averiguar que es ese error y si consigo algo te aviso, de todas maneras el usuario Sal respondio y tambien me funciona.

Comment: @AlbertoMarun El error sale porque el formato de la cadenas ingresadas es `HH:MM`, no tienen segundos.

Comment: Hola @Marcos la respuesta que coloque lo tiene, a cual línea te refieres

Comment: Tu respuesta la tiene, la pregunta no. Por eso le da error el y no a vos.

Comment: @SneiderMuñoz Por favor, si te funciono la repuesta recuerda "ACEPTAR" para que otros Usuarios se beneficien de ella.